# Create new Array based on conditions of what props are received from an Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs-observables

I have **myObservable$** that returns the following array:

```
[
 { "firstProp": "A", "secondProp": "NA", "available": false },
 { "firstProp": "B", "secondProp": "NA", "available": true },
 { "firstProp": "C", "secondProp": "Old", "available": false },
 { "firstProp": "C", "secondProp": "New", "available": false }
]
```

I need a way to create a new array to check for the 'firstProp', and 'available' and  to push into a new array the following structure:

```
[
 { imgSrc: 'pathTo/myImages/file1.svg', badgeStyle: val?.available ? 'fas fa-exclamation-circle fa-lg' : 'fas fa-check-circle fa-lg', cardLabel: 'First Label'},
 { imgSrc: 'pathTo/myImages/file2.svg', badgeStyle: val?.available ? 'fas fa-exclamation-circle fa-lg' : 'fas fa-check-circle fa-lg', cardLabel: 'Second Label'},
 { imgSrc: 'pathTo/myImages/file3.svg', badgeStyle: val?.available ? 'fas fa-exclamation-circle fa-lg' : 'fas fa-check-circle fa-lg', cardLabel: 'Third Label'},
]
```

###### This is my Solution but I feel there might be a better one to what I did:

```
const OBJ1 = { imgSrc: 'pathTo/myImages/file1.svg', badgeStyle: val?.available ? 'fas fa-exclamation-circle fa-lg' : 'fas fa-check-circle fa-lg', cardLabel: 'First Label'};

const OBJ2 = { imgSrc: 'pathTo/myImages/file2.svg', badgeStyle: val?.available ? 'fas fa-exclamation-circle fa-lg' : 'fas fa-check-circle fa-lg', cardLabel: 'Second Label'};

const OBJ3 = { imgSrc: 'pathTo/myImages/file3.svg', badgeStyle: val?.available ? 'fas fa-exclamation-circle fa-lg' : 'fas fa-check-circle fa-lg', cardLabel: 'Third Label'};



myObservable$.subscribe((value) => {
      value?.forEach((val) => {
        if (val?.firstProp === 'A') {
          this.myNewArray.push(OBJ1);
        } else if (val?.firstProp === 'B') {
          this.myNewArray.push(OBJ2);
        } else if (val?.firstProp === 'C' && val?.secondProp === 'New') {
          this.myNewArray.push(OBJ3);
        }
      });
    });
```

###### I am also failing in finding a solution for the case when:

because I get 2 times the 'firstProp' as 'C' with different types of 'secondProp' (Old and New). The rule is that I have to display badgeStyle as 'exclamation' when either one or both 'C' have "available": true and to display the 'green-tick' for badgeStyle when both C have "available": false

Comment: you could make your new array an ```Observable``` also and then just ```pipe``` without having to ```subscribe```.

Comment: How this condition is working?
`badgeStyle: val?.available ? 'fas fa-exclamation-circle fa-lg' : 'fas fa-check-circle fa-lg',`

You don't have `val` property in the object it will always return `false`

Comment: Yes, @Yuriy I have val.available property. It is coming from the array returned by the myObservable  with value?.forEach

Answer (score 0):

Say you have redefined the `myNewArray` property to an `Observable`, the benefits of doing this over the solution you're currently using is that you would not have to worry about unsubscribing to the `Observable` because angular will take care of that part for you. Let us demonstrate below...

```
//...

// so let us start by redefining the myNewArray as the Observable
myNewArray$: Observable<Array<{ imgSrc: string; badgeStyle: string; cardLabel: string }>>;

// you will need to initialize the above ofcourse so we will do this in the
// component constructor
constructor() {
  //... so then you initialize the myObservable property
  // then you assign the myNewArray
  this.myNewArray$ = this.myObservable$.pipe(
    map((value) => {
      if (val?.firstProp === 'A') {
        return OBJ1;
      } else if (val?.firstProp === 'B') {
        return OBJ2;
      } else if (val?.firstProp === 'C' && val?.secondProp === 'New') {
        return OBJ3;
      }
      // you will probably get a ts error for not having an else statement
      // so you will need to accommodate the else state
    })
  );
}

//...
```

From the above you would then use the `async` pipe in your `html` section of your components code.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(myNewArray$ | async) as newdata">
  <!-- content here -->
</ng-container>
```

Hence you have less memory leaks because angular will unsubscribe for you when the
component is destroyed.

Comment: I would not seek to improve the memory leak part now... I'm interested in  a better solution to construct the myNewArray  than the one I did with lots of IF ELSE conditions. That is my main target. How would you do it?